# manually remove asp.net authentication cookies

Tags: asp.net

How do I manually remove a cookie that was set by a subdomain for asp.net authentication?

The cookie was set on `setter.test.com`;

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms domain="test.com" loginUrl="Default.aspx" protection="All" path="/" requireSSL="false" timeout="45" name=".ASPXAUTH" slidingExpiration="true" defaultUrl="Default.aspx" cookieless="UseDeviceProfile" enableCrossAppRedirects="false"/>
</authentication>
```

In my application at `getter.test.com`, this is my code for logging out (removing that cookie):

```
public ActionResult LogOut()
{
        //Manually remove the cookie created by 3rd party authentication
            if (Request.Cookies[".ASPXAUTH"] != null)
            {
                HttpCookie myCookie = new HttpCookie(".ASPXAUTH");
                myCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1d);
                Response.Cookies.Add(myCookie);
            }
}
```

This does not work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One small change and you should be set to go.

```
public ActionResult LogOut()
{
    //Manually remove the cookie created by 3rd party authentication
        if (Request.Cookies[".ASPXAUTH"] != null)
        {
            HttpCookie myCookie = new HttpCookie(".ASPXAUTH");
            myCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1d);
            myCookie.Domain = "test.com";
            Response.Cookies.Add(myCookie);
        }
}
```

You have to be sure that the domain is set the same on both.

Comment: You would need to either read it from a config, or determine it in some manner.  You MUST have it, you might be able to grab it from the request cookie...

Comment: Per [RFC 6265](http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6265.txt) Section 4.2.2: "Notice that the cookie attributes are not returned.  In particular, the server cannot determine from the Cookie header alone when a cookie will expire, for which hosts the cookie is valid, for which paths the cookie is valid, or whether the cookie was set with the Secure or HttpOnly attributes."

Answer (score 3):

Since you can only have one cookie by that name, regardless of the domain, I think that the recommended way to do this is:

```
FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
```

See http://support.microsoft.com/kb/910443

Comment: you can have same name cookie for  .something.com and www.something.com.
when calling SignOut under www you will delete one but not the other.
true story

Comment: Doesn't FormsAuthentication apply to the current application only? So if www.something.com pointed to a different application root you would get a different signin? Never tried it myself.