# Manually remove Auth Cookie from .Net MVC Application

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, cookies, session-cookies, form-authentication

One of my recent .Net MVC based web application i have a situation by which i need to use multiple auth cookie like

1 Forms Auth Cookie

```
FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(1, userName, DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now.AddDays(30), RememberMe, 'data1', FormsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath);
string hash = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(ticket);
HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, hash);
HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
```

2 Custom Auth Cookie

```
FormsAuthenticationTicket cstTicket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(1, Username, DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now.AddDays(30), isPersistent, 'data 2', FormsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath);
string _encryptedTicket = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(cstTicket);
HttpCookie cstCookie = new HttpCookie("iCstm", _encryptedTicket);
HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(cstCookie);
```

I need to remove both the cookie when someone logout from the application. If i call FormsAuthentication.SignOut(); then it remove basic auth cookie. I tried to remove second cookie by setting Expires value like

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["iCstm"].Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddYears(-1);
HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies["iCstm"].Value = "";
HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["iCstm"]);
```

But this will not work in case of auth cookie. Is there ny way to handle this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4739168/manually-remove-asp-net-authentication-cookies)

Comment: @ElmerDantas Thank you for your suggestion. This won't in case of session cookie.

Comment: @Hope - "session cookie" is a feature of some browsers, but is not a standard. There is no way to remove cookies from browsers - it is not something that can be controlled from the server. All you can do is change the cookie's expiration date to a date in the past (and possibly update its contents to be empty) - it is up to the implementation of the browser whether or not the cookie is actually deleted.

Comment: Thank you for your replay @NightOwl888.